# outlook - send "read receipt" to email in "TO LIST" not email in "CC list"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My work requires me to send many email & must be sure that at least, my email has been read when I send them. Because of the rule for "share information", I must CC many people, so if I use "outlook read receipt" then it make so rude, so I post this question to ask:
Assume that I have 3 email id in "TO list" and a group mail id in "CC list". Can we configure Outlook for it send "read receipt" to only 3 email in "TO list"?
Sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to request a read receipt from addresses in the `"TO"` field while excluding the addresses in the `"CC"` field. Not sure what version of Outlook you are using, but here is a work around for Outlook 2010 which uses rules to request read receipts for certain addresses.

[Microsoft Community - Individual Read Receipts](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/individual-read-receipt/7b4c430e-8da6-4bd3-9645-a869dbd9119a)